# First jQuery script, simple Form Focus, any problems?

Tags: jquery

After studying the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) for a while, I came up with my first jQuery script. It's a simple Form Focus script. Just want to make sure I've got this right.

I couldn't find anything that spoke of "conditional statements" with jQuery, so I assume you just use standard JavaScript `if` / `else if` statments.

To test if the `#id` exists, the jQuery docs explained I should use `.length`.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    if ($('#one').length) {
        $('#one').focus();
    }
    else if ($('#two').length ) {
        $('#two').focus();
    }
    else {
        return false; // is this even necessary?
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

It is possible that `#one` and `#two` will exist on the same page, so I want to target `#one` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is functionally correct. As you advance with jQuery though, you will not want to do multiple lookups. This would be a better way of writing it:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var $one = $("#one"), $two = $("#two");
    if ( $one.length ) $one.focus();
    else if ( $two.length ) $two.focus();
});
```

Every time you use $("#id") it performs a lookup. If you can cache it in a variable the first time like `var $one = $("#one")` you can save times on lookups later. The `$` sign in my variable names is completely arbitrary, but it helps you remember which variables have jQuery wrapped objects.

Comment: jQuery uses selector cache internally, though

Comment: @d: Does that mean setting up the `vars` is not important in this case? I was actually just setting up my script this way, but I'd like to hear more about "the selector cache".

Comment: I'll let @d answer, but it might be a good idea anyway. If you don't then you will be more likely to do $("#one .some_child") later than just using $one.find('.some_child'). I am interested to hear more about the internal cache as well.

Comment: I just chatted with Codey Lindey on the jQuery core team. There is no internal selector cache in jQuery. Each time you use the `jQuery()` or `$()` functions, a new jQuery object is created and a new lookup is performed. By caching the jQuery object in a variable, you can really speed up your code.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to test length. if the wrapped set is empty the focus function is called for nothing. if only #one or #two will exist, then the following works fine:

```
$(function() {  // shorthand for $(document).ready()
       $('#one, #two').focus();
});
```

Comment: Great solution Scott. I was thinking there was a better way to do this. Obviously if they both exist this would cause a problem.

Comment: Isn't $(document).ready(function() {}) the preferred jQuery way of doing it since $(function()) just calleds the document ready handler? It's certainly more communicative of the intent of the script.

Comment: @Hooray Im Helping - I think once you are used to the $(function(){...}); syntax for setting up code for the ready handler it helps clear the clutter.

Comment: Your code is almost the same as @duckyflip but you need to add `.filter(:first)` since jeff wants `#one` selected if `#one` and `#two` exist together: `$('#one, #two').filter(':first').focus();`

Answer (score 1):

Your script is accurate, although there's no need, as you anticipated, to return anything in your else clause (or even to have one)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your interface is displayed... for example, will elements one and two exist at the same time, if not, you can do:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#one').focus();
  $('#two').focus();
}
```

If they will exist together on the same page, then this is fine:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  if ($('#one').length) {
    $('#one').focus();
  }
  else {
    $('#two').focus();
  }
}
```

If no elements were returned, the .focus() won't actually fail or anything, so you're free to just do it in 1 line without the conditional.

Also, the return false bit isn't necessary.

Comment: Yes, `#one` and `#two` will exist at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is generally correct, although when using jQuery you can really cut the amount of cheks & detections you'd need with standard Javascript

- Calling a method or property on the jQuery object will not return an error even if the object (e.g `$("#one")` ) was not found
- You can fetch multiple DOM Elements at once (e.g `$("#one,#two")` ) and you can also call a method on all of these objects at once
  `
- There's no need to return anything at the end of your `$(document).load(function(){...})`

So  having all these points in ming you can update your script like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#one,#two').focus();
});
```

**EDIT**:

Since you indicated you want to select `#one` first, in the case when both `#one` and `#two` exist on the same page, all you have to do is put the `#one` reference at the end of the list and it will be the one that always  gets selected if it exists.

```
$('#two,#one').focus();
```

Comment: Is this valid even if `#one` and `#two` will exist at the same time?

Comment: Jeff, this is not true as of the most recent versions of jQuery. Selectors are always returned in document order, so whichever is last in the DOM will be selected.

Comment: @duckyflip: When I first wrote the script, I noticed that. I decided to use `if` / `else if` because I thought, "jQuery is going to first focus on `#one` if it exists, then it will see that `#two` exists and focus on that, and so on...

Comment: Just add a little bit to your selector: `$('#one, #two').filter(':first').focus();` and it will work.

Comment: Both the $('#one, #two').filter(':first') and the $('#two, #one') approaches are dependent on properties of the DOM at hand. if #one is the last element in the DOM, the :first solution will fail, if #one is first in the DOM, the '#two, #one' solution will fail

Comment: @d: Could you post a solution?